# Indexing and searching large set of different format of documents using hadoop and related technologies

Tags: hadoop, full-text-search, bigdata

We in our organization trying to develop some competency around big data **Hadoop** and related eco system.
We are thinking doing a proof of concept in which our objective would be to store, index and search on large set of PDF files, email docs and word docs. First of all i would like to know that is this a big data use case?
If it is, then is it a hadoop use case? If it is then what all technologies we should go for?

We tried storing PDF in **HDFS** and successfully created **lucene** indexes via mapper jobs in parallel and store indexes at data node local temporary directory.
But we are not sure if we doing it right way or not, how to make it a proper big data **Hadoop** use case, and struggling around making a decision on tech stack whether **Hadoop** or a **no SQL** db or **Elasticsearch** or **SOLR** etc etc...

Our objective is to do a proof of concept around searching on large set of different format of docs and we wanted to use **Hadoop** if possible... Can anybody please help us to get right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you will find some interesting things in this paper: http://terrierteam.dcs.gla.ac.uk/publications/IPM_MapReduce.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to do any analysis on the data on files stored in HDFS, Hadoop might not be your right choice. If you have unstructured or semi-structured data and want to crunch these into tables for future analysis, you can use HDFS with Hive/Pig to extract them. you might not need NoSQL unless you want high-availability or consistency which in your case I don't think so.